# TestCafe - Checking if the hyperlink is working - redirection to an external email provider

Tags: typescript, testing, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

On the website is e-mail address (hyperlink) e.g. example@gmail.com, in one of the test scenarios I would like to click on this link and check if the user is redirected to an external e-mail provider, e.g. outlook. Can I do something like that in TestCafe?

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe is designed to interact with the web browser and does not provide a mechanism to track external processes. Thus, it is impossible to verify whether or not an email client application was launched.

At the same time, I do not completely understand the necessity to check if a email client is launching: this behavior is controlled by the operating system and may vary between different machines. It might be more reliable to test whether or not the "mailto" URL is correct. If this works for you, you can use the following code for this purpose:

```
await t.expect(Selector('#anchor').getAttribute('href')).eql('mailto:name@mail.com?subject=The%20subject&amp;body=This%20is%20a%20message%20body');
```